# AWS Redshift : libraries for mock/mirror redshift

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, automated-tests, amazon-redshift

Is there a library for mocking/mirroring Redshift SQL interface to run tests in an isolated dev environment ?

If not, please point to suggested best practices for such testing ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amazon Redshift was specifically created to run on AWS infrastructure. It is not available as a download. (Interestingly, Amazon DynamoDB does have a downloadable version for development purposes.)

The cheapest option might be to **shutdown your Dev & Test instances each night** and on weekends. Take a snapshot before deleting the cluster, then create a cluster the next morning based on the snapshot. This can be automated via the AWS Command-Line Interface (CLI), making it easy to schedule with cron or Scheduled Tasks.

You could also have a **snapshot** of Test data and restore that snapshot each morning, which means the test database doesn't fill-up with test cases.

Another cost saving might be to **reduce the number of nodes for the non-production systems**. Queries will run slower and the total amount of storage will be reduced, but it could be more cost-effective. Or even use a "Dense Storage" 2TB node instead of several "Dense Compute" SSD instances -- they will provide more storage on less nodes.

Answer (score 5):

If your application is written in Java, you can intercept and mock Redshift specific commands via custom JDBC driver.

Custom JDBC driver will work as follows.

- Parse the given statement.
- If statement is COPY, download data from S3 then insert.
- If statement is UNLOAD, select from target table, then upload to S3.

I've just released [redshift-fake-driver](https://github.com/opt-tech/redshift-fake-driver), a JDBC driver emulates Redshift specific commands.
I hope this will help you.

Comment: +1 This is a fantastic project, I'm using it along LocalStack to simulate Redshift in my end-to-end tests. It's a JDBC driver (JAR file) but you can use it from Python as well via the [JayDeBeApi](https://pypi.org/project/JayDeBeApi/) package. Recommended!

Answer (score 3):

Redshift SQL quacks mostly like PostgreSQL and I have had 'some' success with a mock db that is just postgres. TBH I eventually ripped that out, principally because window functions were just so darn different between the two.